# Recording Android user input for automated replay (automated testing)

Tags: android, automated-tests, monkeyrunner

Does anyway know of an open source solution for recording user input.
The ideal one would output monkeyrunner script.

I'm happy to modify my source by extending input recording classes, which would be the simplest solution, i.e. extend the base View and Activity classes to catch the onTouchEvent(), onKeyUp(), onKeyDown(), etc, and then generate the monkeyrunner script in there to be written out. But it seems a shame to write it if it already exists!

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

[FoneMonkey for Android](https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/fonemonkey-android) is open source and would help you achieve your goal.

Also, [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) with its simple to use UI (see [Culebra-GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI)), let you create powerful python scripts (no monkeyrunner needed) that you can further customize to suite your most demanding needs.

Comment: FoneMonkey url is inaccessible